# how to get "Welcome to React" webpage when running `create-react-app` example?

Tags: npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to get `create-react-app` working with npm version `6.4.1`

I simply run `create-react-app myApp`, having previously running `npm install --global create-react-app`.
Then I entried into `myApp` folder and run `npm start` and get

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view memory in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://172.17.0.4:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

But when I go to http://localhost:3000/, i get a blank page.
Please note that i run `npm` inside a Docker container and that port forwarding has been correctly set.

By the way, running `curl localhost:3000` provide me a html containing :

```
This HTML file is a template.
If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
```

I have followed [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md) for browser support : I have added `react-app-polyfill` module and importing `react-app-polyfill/ie11` at first line of `src/index.js` to make my app compatible with internet explorer 11 I'm using... but unsucessfuly

[Update]
Looking at chrome debug mode, I noticed that `static/js/bundle.js` is displayed like :

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><title>Domino</title><link href="/static/css/main.2a4f1b23.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><script>0</script><script>window.__env = window.__env || {};
  window.__env["MIXPANEL_TOKEN"] = '012180ff05d2eed2f8904117d919a433';</script><div id="root"></div>
          <!-- intercom -->



    <script id="IntercomSettingsScriptTag">
          window.intercomSettings = {

            "domino_version": "3.4.10",
            "domino_major": 3,
            "domino_minor": 4,
            email: "youcef.k@toto.com",
            username: "youcef_k_b0984",
            name: "Youcef K",
            user_hash : "1bccc22bcfd345d0bbe9ce7de329975144f075056c966feec5346720e1a5aa92",



              companies: [{"company_id": "toto.com", "name":"toto.com"}],

            created_at: 1539174731 ,
            hostname: window.location.hostname,
            widget: { activator: "#IntercomDefaultWidget" },
            app_id: "ca1ff9b9b3e6ec502dd74ef8356046ed57cefec8",
            app_user: true,
            plan: 'none',
            marketing_opt_in: "false"
          };
        </script>
    <script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://static.intercomcdn.com/intercom.v1.js';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}};})()</script>


          <!-- oidcIframes -->







<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.aecf19f7.js"></script></body></html>
```

Normally this file should be like:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // install a JSONP callback for chunk loading
/******/    function webpackJsonpCallback(data) {
/******/        var chunkIds = data[0];
/******/        var moreModules = data[1];
/******/        var executeModules = data[2];
/******/
/******/        // add "moreModules" to the modules object,
/******/        // then flag all "chunkIds" as loaded and fire callback
/******/        var moduleId, chunkId, i = 0, resolves = [];
/******/        for(;i < chunkIds.length; i++) {
/******/            chunkId = chunkIds[i];
/******/            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(installedChunks, chunkId) && installedChunks[chunkId]) {
/******/                resolves.push(installedChunks[chunkId][0]);
/******/            }
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = 0;
/******/        }
/******/        for(moduleId in moreModules) {
/******/            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(moreModules, moduleId)) {
/******/                modules[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/        if(parentJsonpFunction) parentJsonpFunction(data);
/******/
/******/        while(resolves.length) {
/******/            resolves.shift()();
/******/        }
/******/
/******/        // add entry modules from loaded chunk to deferred list
/******/        deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
/******/
/******/        // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
/******/        return checkDeferredModules();
/******/    };
/******/    function checkDeferredModules() {
/******/        var result;
/******/        for(var i = 0; i < deferredModules.length; i++) {
/******/            var deferredModule = deferredModules[i];
/******/            var fulfilled = true;
/******/            for(var j = 1; j < deferredModule.length; j++) {
/******/                var depId = deferredModule[j];
/******/                if(installedChunks[depId] !== 0) fulfilled = false;
/******/            }
/******/            if(fulfilled) {
/******/                deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
/******/                result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/
/******/        return result;
/******/    }
/******/    function hotDisposeChunk(chunkId) {
/******/        delete installedChunks[chunkId];
/******/    }
/******/    var parentHotUpdateCallback = window["webpackHotUpdate"];
/******/    window["webpackHotUpdate"] = // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    function webpackHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules) {
/******/        hotAddUpdateChunk(chunkId, moreModules);
/******/        if (parentHotUpdateCallback) parentHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules);
/******/    } ;
/******/
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    function hotDownloadUpdateChunk(chunkId) {
/******/        var script = document.createElement("script");
/******/        script.charset = "utf-8";
/******/        script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + "." + hotCurrentHash + ".hot-update.js";
/******/        if (null) script.crossOrigin = null;
/******/        document.head.appendChild(script);
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    function hotDownloadManifest(requestTimeout) {
/******/        requestTimeout = requestTimeout || 10000;
/******/        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
/******/            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined") {
/******/                return reject(new Error("No browser support"));
/******/            }
/******/            try {
/******/                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
/******/                var requestPath = __webpack_require__.p + "" + hotCurrentHash + ".hot-update.json";
/******/                request.open("GET", requestPath, true);
/******/                request.timeout = requestTimeout;
/******/                request.send(null);
/******/            } catch (err) {
/******/                return reject(err);
/******/            }
/******/            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
/******/                if (request.readyState !== 4) return;
/******/                if (request.status === 0) {
/******/                    // timeout
/******/                    reject(
/******/                        new Error("Manifest request to " + requestPath + " timed out.")
/******/                    );
/******/                } else if (request.status === 404) {
/******/                    // no update available
/******/                    resolve();
/******/                } else if (request.status !== 200 && request.status !== 304) {
/******/                    // other failure
/******/                    reject(new Error("Manifest request to " + requestPath + " failed."));
/******/                } else {
/******/                    // success
/******/                    try {
/******/                        var update = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
/******/                    } catch (e) {
/******/                        reject(e);
/******/                        return;
/******/                    }
/******/                    resolve(update);
/******/                }
/******/            };
/******/        });
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    var hotApplyOnUpdate = true;
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    var hotCurrentHash = "8f3a97dce2272b12b605";
/******/    var hotRequestTimeout = 10000;
/******/    var hotCurrentModuleData = {};
/******/    var hotCurrentChildModule;
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    var hotCurrentParents = [];
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    var hotCurrentParentsTemp = [];
/******/
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    function hotCreateRequire(moduleId) {
/******/        var me = installedModules[moduleId];
/******/        if (!me) return __webpack_require__;
/******/        var fn = function(request) {
/******/            if (me.hot.active) {
/******/                if (installedModules[request]) {
/******/                    if (installedModules[request].parents.indexOf(moduleId) === -1) {
/******/                        installedModules[request].parents.push(moduleId);
/******/                    }
/******/                } else {
/******/                    hotCurrentParents = [moduleId];
/******/                    hotCurrentChildModule = request;
/******/                }
/******/                if (me.children.indexOf(request) === -1) {
/******/                    me.children.push(request);
/******/                }
/******/            } else {
/******/                console.warn(
/******/                    "[HMR] unexpected require(" +
/******/                        request +
/******/                        ") from disposed module " +
/******/                        moduleId
/******/                );
/******/                hotCurrentParents = [];
/******/            }
/******/            return __webpack_require__(request);
/******/        };
/******/        var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
/******/            return {
/******/                configurable: true,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: function() {
/******/                    return __webpack_require__[name];
/******/                },
/******/                set: function(value) {
/******/                    __webpack_require__[name] = value;
/******/                }
/******/            };
/******/        };
/******/        for (var name in __webpack_require__) {
/******/            if (
/******/                Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(__webpack_require__, name) &&
/******/                name !== "e" &&
/******/                name !== "t"
/******/            ) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(fn, name, ObjectFactory(name));
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/        fn.e = function(chunkId) {
/******/            if (hotStatus === "ready") hotSetStatus("prepare");
/******/            hotChunksLoading++;
/******/            return __webpack_require__.e(chunkId).then(finishChunkLoading, function(err) {
/******/                finishChunkLoading();
/******/                throw err;
/******/            });
/******/
/******/            function finishChunkLoading() {
/******/                hotChunksLoading--;
/******/                if (hotStatus === "prepare") {
/******/                    if (!hotWaitingFilesMap[chunkId]) {
/******/                        hotEnsureUpdateChunk(chunkId);
/******/                    }
/******/                    if (hotChunksLoading === 0 && hotWaitingFiles === 0) {
/******/                        hotUpdateDownloaded();
/******/                    }
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/        };
/******/        fn.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/            if (mode & 1) value = fn(value);
/******/            return __webpack_require__.t(value, mode & ~1);
/******/        };
/******/        return fn;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    function hotCreateModule(moduleId) {
/******/        var hot = {
/******/            // private stuff
/******/            _acceptedDependencies: {},
/******/            _declinedDependencies: {},
/******/            _selfAccepted: false,
/******/            _selfDeclined: false,
/******/            _disposeHandlers: [],
/******/            _main: hotCurrentChildModule !== moduleId,
/******/
/******/            // Module API
/******/            active: true,
/******/            accept: function(dep, callback) {
/******/                if (dep === undefined) hot._selfAccepted = true;
/******/                else if (typeof dep === "function") hot._selfAccepted = dep;
/******/                else if (typeof dep === "object")
/******/                    for (var i = 0; i < dep.length; i++)
/******/                        hot._acceptedDependencies[dep[i]] = callback || function() {};
/******/                else hot._acceptedDependencies[dep] = callback || function() {};
/******/            },
/******/            decline: function(dep) {
/******/                if (dep === undefined) hot._selfDeclined = true;
/******/                else if (typeof dep === "object")
/******/                    for (var i = 0; i < dep.length; i++)
/******/                        hot._declinedDependencies[dep[i]] = true;
/******/                else hot._declinedDependencies[dep] = true;
/******/            },
/******/            dispose: function(callback) {
/******/                hot._disposeHandlers.push(callback);
/******/            },
/******/            addDisposeHandler: function(callback) {
/******/                hot._disposeHandlers.push(callback);
/******/            },
/******/            removeDisposeHandler: function(callback) {
/******/                var idx = hot._disposeHandlers.indexOf(callback);
/******/                if (idx >= 0) hot._disposeHandlers.splice(idx, 1);
/******/            },
/******/
/******/            // Management API
/******/            check: hotCheck,
/******/            apply: hotApply,
/******/            status: function(l) {
/******/                if (!l) return hotStatus;
/******/                hotStatusHandlers.push(l);
/******/            },
/******/            addStatusHandler: function(l) {
/******/                hotStatusHandlers.push(l);
/******/            },
/******/            removeStatusHandler: function(l) {
/******/                var idx = hotStatusHandlers.indexOf(l);
/******/                if (idx >= 0) hotStatusHandlers.splice(idx, 1);
/******/            },
/******/
/******/            //inherit from previous dispose call
/******/            data: hotCurrentModuleData[moduleId]
/******/        };
/******/        hotCurrentChildModule = undefined;
/******/        return hot;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    var hotStatusHandlers = [];
/******/    var hotStatus = "idle";
/******/
/******/    function hotSetStatus(newStatus) {
/******/        hotStatus = newStatus;
/******/        for (var i = 0; i < hotStatusHandlers.length; i++)
/******/            hotStatusHandlers[i].call(null, newStatus);
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    // while downloading
/******/    var hotWaitingFiles = 0;
/******/    var hotChunksLoading = 0;
/******/    var hotWaitingFilesMap = {};
/******/    var hotRequestedFilesMap = {};
/******/    var hotAvailableFilesMap = {};
/******/    var hotDeferred;
/******/
/******/    // The update info
/******/    var hotUpdate, hotUpdateNewHash;
/******/
/******/    function toModuleId(id) {
/******/        var isNumber = +id + "" === id;
/******/        return isNumber ? +id : id;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    function hotCheck(apply) {
/******/        if (hotStatus !== "idle") {
/******/            throw new Error("check() is only allowed in idle status");
/******/        }
/******/        hotApplyOnUpdate = apply;
/******/        hotSetStatus("check");
/******/        return hotDownloadManifest(hotRequestTimeout).then(function(update) {
/******/            if (!update) {
/******/                hotSetStatus("idle");
/******/                return null;
/******/            }
/******/            hotRequestedFilesMap = {};
/******/            hotWaitingFilesMap = {};
/******/            hotAvailableFilesMap = update.c;
/******/            hotUpdateNewHash = update.h;
/******/
/******/            hotSetStatus("prepare");
/******/            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
/******/                hotDeferred = {
/******/                    resolve: resolve,
/******/                    reject: reject
/******/                };
/******/            });
/******/            hotUpdate = {};
/******/            for(var chunkId in installedChunks)
/******/            // eslint-disable-next-line no-lone-blocks
/******/            {
/******/                /*globals chunkId */
/******/                hotEnsureUpdateChunk(chunkId);
/******/            }
/******/            if (
/******/                hotStatus === "prepare" &&
/******/                hotChunksLoading === 0 &&
/******/                hotWaitingFiles === 0
/******/            ) {
/******/                hotUpdateDownloaded();
/******/            }
/******/            return promise;
/******/        });
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
/******/    function hotAddUpdateChunk(chunkId, moreModules) {
/******/        if (!hotAvailableFilesMap[chunkId] || !hotRequestedFilesMap[chunkId])
/******/            return;
/******/        hotRequestedFilesMap[chunkId] = false;
/******/        for (var moduleId in moreModules) {
/******/            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(moreModules, moduleId)) {
/******/                hotUpdate[moduleId] = moreModules[moduleId];
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/        if (--hotWaitingFiles === 0 && hotChunksLoading === 0) {
/******/            hotUpdateDownloaded();
/******/        }
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    function hotEnsureUpdateChunk(chunkId) {
/******/        if (!hotAvailableFilesMap[chunkId]) {
/******/            hotWaitingFilesMap[chunkId] = true;
/******/        } else {
/******/            hotRequestedFilesMap[chunkId] = true;
/******/            hotWaitingFiles++;
/******/            hotDownloadUpdateChunk(chunkId);
/******/        }
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    function hotUpdateDownloaded() {
/******/        hotSetStatus("ready");
/******/        var deferred = hotDeferred;
/******/        hotDeferred = null;
/******/        if (!deferred) return;
/******/        if (hotApplyOnUpdate) {
/******/            // Wrap deferred object in Promise to mark it as a well-handled Promise to
/******/            // avoid triggering uncaught exception warning in Chrome.
/******/            // See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465666
/******/            Promise.resolve()
/******/                .then(function() {
/******/                    return hotApply(hotApplyOnUpdate);
/******/                })
/******/                .then(
/******/                    function(result) {
/******/                        deferred.resolve(result);
/******/                    },
/******/                    function(err) {
/******/                        deferred.reject(err);
/******/                    }
/******/                );
/******/        } else {
/******/            var outdatedModules = [];
/******/            for (var id in hotUpdate) {
/******/                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(hotUpdate, id)) {
/******/                    outdatedModules.push(toModuleId(id));
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/            deferred.resolve(outdatedModules);
/******/        }
/******/    }
/******/
/******/    function hotApply(options) {
/******/        if (hotStatus !== "ready")
/******/            throw new Error("apply() is only allowed in ready status");
/******/        options = options || {};
/******/
/******/        var cb;
/******/        var i;
/******/        var j;
/******/        var module;
/******/        var moduleId;
/******/
/******/        function getAffectedStuff(updateModuleId) {
/******/            var outdatedModules = [updateModuleId];
/******/            var outdatedDependencies = {};
/******/
/******/            var queue = outdatedModules.map(function(id) {
/******/                return {
/******/                    chain: [id],
/******/                    id: id
/******/                };
/******/            });
/******/            while (queue.length > 0) {
/******/                var queueItem = queue.pop();
/******/                var moduleId = queueItem.id;
/******/                var chain = queueItem.chain;
/******/                module = installedModules[moduleId];
/******/                if (!module || module.hot._selfAccepted) continue;
/******/                if (module.hot._selfDeclined) {
/******/                    return {
/******/                        type: "self-declined",
/******/                        chain: chain,
/******/                        moduleId: moduleId
/******/                    };
/******/                }
/******/                if (module.hot._main) {
/******/                    return {
/******/                        type: "unaccepted",
/******/                        chain: chain,
/******/                        moduleId: moduleId
/******/                    };
/******/                }
/******/                for (var i = 0; i < module.parents.length; i++) {
/******/                    var parentId = module.parents[i];
/******/                    var parent = installedModules[parentId];
/******/                    if (!parent) continue;
/******/                    if (parent.hot._declinedDependencies[moduleId]) {
/******/                        return {
/******/                            type: "declined",
/******/                            chain: chain.concat([parentId]),
/******/                            moduleId: moduleId,
/******/                            parentId: parentId
/******/                        };
/******/                    }
/******/                    if (outdatedModules.indexOf(parentId) !== -1) continue;
/******/                    if (parent.hot._acceptedDependencies[moduleId]) {
/******/                        if (!outdatedDependencies[parentId])
/******/                            outdatedDependencies[parentId] = [];
/******/                        addAllToSet(outdatedDependencies[parentId], [moduleId]);
/******/                        continue;
/******/                    }
/******/                    delete outdatedDependencies[parentId];
/******/                    outdatedModules.push(parentId);
/******/                    queue.push({
/******/                        chain: chain.concat([parentId]),
/******/                        id: parentId
/******/                    });
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/
/******/            return {
/******/                type: "accepted",
/******/                moduleId: updateModuleId,
/******/                outdatedModules: outdatedModules,
/******/                outdatedDependencies: outdatedDependencies
/******/            };
/******/        }
/******/
/******/        function addAllToSet(a, b) {
/******/            for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
/******/                var item = b[i];
/******/                if (a.indexOf(item) === -1) a.push(item);
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/
/******/        // at begin all updates modules are outdated
/******/        // the "outdated" status can propagate to parents if they don't accept the children
/******/        var outdatedDependencies = {};
/******/        var outdatedModules = [];
/******/        var appliedUpdate = {};
/******/
/******/        var warnUnexpectedRequire = function warnUnexpectedRequire() {
/******/            console.warn(
/******/                "[HMR] unexpected require(" + result.moduleId + ") to disposed module"
/******/            );
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        for (var id in hotUpdate) {
/******/            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(hotUpdate, id)) {
/******/                moduleId = toModuleId(id);
/******/                /** @type {TODO} */
/******/                var result;
/******/                if (hotUpdate[id]) {
/******/                    result = getAffectedStuff(moduleId);
/******/                } else {
/******/                    result = {
/******/                        type: "disposed",
/******/                        moduleId: id
/******/                    };
/******/                }
/******/                /** @type {Error|false} */
/******/                var abortError = false;
/******/                var doApply = false;
/******/                var doDispose = false;
/******/                var chainInfo = "";
/******/                if (result.chain) {
/******/                    chainInfo = "\nUpdate propagation: " + result.chain.join(" -> ");
/******/                }
/******/                switch (result.type) {
/******/                    case "self-declined":
/******/                        if (options.onDeclined) options.onDeclined(result);
/******/                        if (!options.ignoreDeclined)
/******/                            abortError = new Error(
/******/                                "Aborted because of self decline: " +
/******/                                    result.moduleId +
/******/                                    chainInfo
/******/                            );
/******/                        break;
/******/                    case "declined":
/******/                        if (options.onDeclined) options.onDeclined(result);
/******/                        if (!options.ignoreDeclined)
/******/                            abortError = new Error(
/******/                                "Aborted because of declined dependency: " +
/******/                                    result.moduleId +
/******/                                    " in " +
/******/                                    result.parentId +
/******/                                    chainInfo
/******/                            );
/******/                        break;
/******/                    case "unaccepted":
/******/                        if (options.onUnaccepted) options.onUnaccepted(result);
/******/                        if (!options.ignoreUnaccepted)
/******/                            abortError = new Error(
/******/                                "Aborted because " + moduleId + " is not accepted" + chainInfo
/******/                            );
/******/                        break;
/******/                    case "accepted":
/******/                        if (options.onAccepted) options.onAccepted(result);
/******/                        doApply = true;
/******/                        break;
/******/                    case "disposed":
/******/                        if (options.onDisposed) options.onDisposed(result);
/******/                        doDispose = true;
/******/                        break;
/******/                    default:
/******/                        throw new Error("Unexception type " + result.type);
/******/                }
/******/                if (abortError) {
/******/                    hotSetStatus("abort");
/******/                    return Promise.reject(abortError);
/******/                }
/******/                if (doApply) {
/******/                    appliedUpdate[moduleId] = hotUpdate[moduleId];
/******/                    addAllToSet(outdatedModules, result.outdatedModules);
/******/                    for (moduleId in result.outdatedDependencies) {
/******/                        if (
/******/                            Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(
/******/                                result.outdatedDependencies,
/******/                                moduleId
/******/                            )
/******/                        ) {
/******/                            if (!outdatedDependencies[moduleId])
/******/                                outdatedDependencies[moduleId] = [];
/******/                            addAllToSet(
/******/                                outdatedDependencies[moduleId],
/******/                                result.outdatedDependencies[moduleId]
/******/                            );
/******/                        }
/******/                    }
/******/                }
/******/                if (doDispose) {
/******/                    addAllToSet(outdatedModules, [result.moduleId]);
/******/                    appliedUpdate[moduleId] = warnUnexpectedRequire;
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/
/******/        // Store self accepted outdated modules to require them later by the module system
/******/        var outdatedSelfAcceptedModules = [];
/******/        for (i = 0; i < outdatedModules.length; i++) {
/******/            moduleId = outdatedModules[i];
/******/            if (
/******/                installedModules[moduleId] &&
/******/                installedModules[moduleId].hot._selfAccepted &&
/******/                // removed self-accepted modules should not be required
/******/                appliedUpdate[moduleId] !== warnUnexpectedRequire
/******/            ) {
/******/                outdatedSelfAcceptedModules.push({
/******/                    module: moduleId,
/******/                    errorHandler: installedModules[moduleId].hot._selfAccepted
/******/                });
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/
/******/        // Now in "dispose" phase
/******/        hotSetStatus("dispose");
/******/        Object.keys(hotAvailableFilesMap).forEach(function(chunkId) {
/******/            if (hotAvailableFilesMap[chunkId] === false) {
/******/                hotDisposeChunk(chunkId);
/******/            }
/******/        });
/******/
/******/        var idx;
/******/        var queue = outdatedModules.slice();
/******/        while (queue.length > 0) {
/******/            moduleId = queue.pop();
/******/            module = installedModules[moduleId];
/******/            if (!module) continue;
/******/
/******/            var data = {};
/******/
/******/            // Call dispose handlers
/******/            var disposeHandlers = module.hot._disposeHandlers;
/******/            for (j = 0; j < disposeHandlers.length; j++) {
/******/                cb = disposeHandlers[j];
/******/                cb(data);
/******/            }
/******/            hotCurrentModuleData[moduleId] = data;
/******/
/******/            // disable module (this disables requires from this module)
/******/            module.hot.active = false;
/******/
/******/            // remove module from cache
/******/            delete installedModules[moduleId];
/******/
/******/            // when disposing there is no need to call dispose handler
/******/            delete outdatedDependencies[moduleId];
/******/
/******/            // remove "parents" references from all children
/******/            for (j = 0; j < module.children.length; j++) {
/******/                var child = installedModules[module.children[j]];
/******/                if (!child) continue;
/******/                idx = child.parents.indexOf(moduleId);
/******/                if (idx >= 0) {
/******/                    child.parents.splice(idx, 1);
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/
/******/        // remove outdated dependency from module children
/******/        var dependency;
/******/        var moduleOutdatedDependencies;
/******/        for (moduleId in outdatedDependencies) {
/******/            if (
/******/                Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(outdatedDependencies, moduleId)
/******/            ) {
/******/                module = installedModules[moduleId];
/******/                if (module) {
/******/                    moduleOutdatedDependencies = outdatedDependencies[moduleId];
/******/                    for (j = 0; j < moduleOutdatedDependencies.length; j++) {
/******/                        dependency = moduleOutdatedDependencies[j];
/******/                        idx = module.children.indexOf(dependency);
/******/                        if (idx >= 0) module.children.splice(idx, 1);
/******/                    }
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/        }
/******/

...
...
...
```

Please note that I work on a collaborative platform, so i have to request a central server that dispatch my request to the right server (i.e. where a container docker is deploying react app in dev mode)

Thanks for any help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Run `ipconfig` (or your OS's equivalent) in Docker and then navigate to the resulting IP address in your host machine's browser.

Comment: I can reach the page from outside container but the page is blank

Comment: You mentioned you're using ie11, does anything different happen if you use Chrome instead?

Comment: Unfortunately same behaviour with chrome.